# x86 asm convert 16bit value to 8bit?

Tags: assembly, x86

Some background info:
I am currently writing a bootloader in protected mode while learning intel x86 assembly. The final result will be a "BootLoader ASCII snake" game.

What I want to do is to pop a value from the stack into the AL register. This gives me a error and I therefore assume I have to pop a value into a 16bit register. This gets me to the point where I need to copy the first 8 bits in the 16bit register to my 8bit register?

This is the instruction reference I am using:
http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html

From the reference linked I see instructions for converting byte to word for example. All the conversion instructions seems to go from a lower register to a bigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `AX` register represents `AH` and `AL` registers so that `AL` represents bits 0-7 and `AH` bits 8-15. If you put ie. 0xef80 to `AX` then `AH` would be 0xef and `AL` would be 0x80.

Comment: Yeah... in a 16 bit environment you can't pop per 8-bit. All push and pop commands will use the full register. So you just do `pop AX` and then use the `AL` part of it.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this! Makes perfect sense, now I can sleep. Thanks!